# Rについて全てのオブジェクトに同じ処理を行いたい

Tags: r

現在、Rを用いた分析を行なっている初心者なのですが、不明点が発生した為
この場を借りて質問させていただきます。

コンパイラには、Rstudioを利用しています。

右上に読み込み済みデータを確認できる"Data"という箇所にすでに読み込み済み.CSVファイルが
**100件**あるのですが、**全て名前が異なり**、各データに含まれる列に新たな項目として、**100件ごとに.CSVファイルの名前を追加**したいと考えております。これfor文等を用いて自動で追加できるようにしたいのですが、わからない為どなたか詳しい方にご教授いただきたいです。

（例）
a.csv
b.csv
c.csv
・
・
・
に対してaの中身(行列)が
　123456
A
B
C
D
だとするなら、7列目にnameという列名を追加し、
7列目に中身を全て"a"を格納したいです。
同じ作業をa.csv,b.csv,c.csvと全て行いたいです。

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

dir_path <- "YOUR_PATH"
files <- dir(path = dir_path, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE) # ファイルの一覧をフルパスで取得する
file_names <- str_sub(string = basename(files),  start = 1, end = -5) # ファイル名の非拡張子部分を取得する

# forによる処理

results <- NULL # 結果をおさめる入れ物を作る
for(i in seq_along(file_names)){
  result <- read_csv(files[i])
  result$name <- file_names[i]
  results[[i]] <- result
}
print(results)
```

tidyverseパッケージを多用する以下のようなアプローチもあります。

```
map2(.x = files, .y = file_names, .f = ~ read_csv(.x) %>% mutate(name = .y))
```